# Find point in Polygon/MultiLineStrings with multiple interior areas, using Shapely and JSON

Tags: geojson, shapely, point-in-polygon

I've been working on this for a few days, adding in features, and fixing the problems as they crop up.

The goal is to read in a CSV containing addresses for locates, parse/normalize them (that functionality will come later), geocode them, and compare them to our service territory, which I currently have as both a KML and GeoJSON (I used Ogre to conver the KML). [I've uploaded the JSON to PasteBin.](http://pastebin.com/5nWd98jj) I've made a very simplified program that only reads in a point and compares it to the JSON for now.

Our service area is bounded on the outside, and within it, there are several other areas that we do not service, with the exception of two - those two I've added placemarkers, which I assume I could check for. My first thought was to use Shapely's contains function, but after trying, and reading the documentation, I don't know if it would deal with the MultiLineStrings making up my boundaries.

The only way I get a positive hit out of this program is if I put in one of the two Points I made. I've tried inside the main boundary, inside a smaller bounding box (non-serviced area) inside that, and inside the boxes that we do service.

```
import json, shapely, time

from shapely.geometry import Point, shape#, MultiLineString

jsonFile = 'P:/Territory.json'

point = Point(-86.76642, 40.67597)

with open(jsonFile, 'r') as jsonFile:
    js = json.load(jsonFile)

    for feature in js['features']:
        #polygon = MultiLineString(feature['geometry'])
        polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
        if polygon.contains(point):
            print("In our territory." + str(feature))
            time.sleep(2)
        #else:
            #print("Not in our territory.")
```

The MultiLineString was throwing a KeyError: 0 (I can include the entire traceback if needed), so I commented it out and tried polygon. The else is commented out because as written, it checks every feature for a match, and generates a huge list of Nopes. I can fix that later; right now I just want to get the point in polygon working correctly.

It's also worth mentioning that I'm happy to use any Python library and file format to accomplish this. I also have an Arc license if arcpy has anything of use here.

Comment: You must build a polygon from the linestrings before you can use "contains", or acquire a new dataset that has your service area as a polygon.

Comment: I'm working on trying to convert them into a polygon now.

Comment: I wound up downloading qGIS, and running Vector --> Geometry --> Lines to Polygons. It didn't convert quite right, as it added some extra lines that aren't in the original.

That aside, while my program now happily loads the GeoJSON I exported, it reports everything as being outside the territory. I tried inside the main boundary, some inside boxes, and outside the main boundary.

The GeoJSON shows up as type: Polygon, with one giant group of coordinates, Long/Lat.

Comment: Are you sure that your GeoJSON is correct? Coordinates seem to be WGS84 (EPSG:4326) but the crs claims something else.